# Obtaining 2 items from MySQL, using a single query by ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple script, but it has just got a little more complex, at least for me.

so here it is, I need to request 2 menu buttons from table which contains all of them together. ID for both is known as it is already rendered by another script on the same page and wrapped in variables `$cat_main_id` and `$cat_add_id`. So here is my script, well at least a top part of it and my question is how I can get both menu buttons to be obtained by the same query, if that is actually possible?

```
    if ($cat_main_id > 0) {
    $menu_query = 'SELECT * FROM lcategories WHERE ID in ( :id , :id2 )';
    $res = $db->prepare($menu_query);
    $res->execute(array(':id' => $cat_main_id, ':id2' => $cat_add_id));
    foreach ($res as $info);
} else {
    echo '';
}
while ($info = $res -> fetch()){
    $category_name = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $info['category_name']);
    $category_page = $info['category_page'];
    $category_dir = $info['category_folder'];
    $category_link = DS.$category_dir.DS.$category_page;
print<<<END

<div class="post_cat">Posted in category <a href="$category_link" class="cat">$category_name</a> <a href="$category_link" class="cat">$category_name</a></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

END;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes easily, the key will be when you then get the results back to identify which row is which button

```
if($cat_main_id > 0 && $cat_add_id > 0){
  $menu_query = 'SELECT * FROM lcategories WHERE ID in ( :id , :id2 )';
  $res = $db->prepare($menu_query);
  $res->execute(array(':id' => $cat_main_id, ,':id2' => $cat_add_id));
}else{
  die(header("Location: error.php"));
};
```

Comment: you are exactly right, now I am having trouble in identifying which result goes where. Ups!!!

Comment: when you iterate over the two rows just compare the ID field to your variable cat_main_id , if it equals you now its cat_main, else it is cat_add

Comment: p.s while I appreciate the Ups, up voting my answer is appreciated much more :)

Comment: I have just updated my question and posted entire script, can you please have a look at it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks good, though it appears that you are just printing the buttons in which ever order they come out of the DB, you may want to force the order either in PHP or in your SQL script, an easy way to force one to come first you could do a small change to your sql script

$menu_query = 'SELECT * FROM lcategories WHERE ID in ( :id , :id2 ) ORDER BY ID=:id';

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($cat_main_id > 0) {
    $menu_query = 'SELECT * FROM lcategories WHERE ID = :id OR ID = :id2';
    $res = $db->prepare($menu_query);
    $res->execute(array(':id' => $cat_main_id, ':id2' => $cat_add_id));
} else {
    die(header("Location: error.php"));
}
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM lcategories WHERE ID IN (:id, :id2)` - and we see one of the limitations of prepared statements: You cannot have infinite parameters to easily extend this query to more than two ids.

Comment: I do not think I'll ever need more than 2 anyway. Thanks. Going to give a try and come back in 2 min

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IN query like so:

```
if ($cat_main_id > 0)
{
  $menu_query = 'SELECT * FROM lcategories WHERE ID IN (:id1, :id2)';
  $res = $db->prepare($menu_query);
  $res->execute(array(':id1' => $cat_main_id, ':id2' => $cat_add_id));
}
else
{
  header("Location: error.php");
  die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to JimiDini's answer, but I prefer `IN` instead of `OR`. It doesn't make much difference for just two IDs, but if there were many of them I think it's much clearer to put them in a single list.

```
if ($cat_main_id > 0) {
    $menu_query = 'SELECT * FROM lcategories WHERE ID IN (:id, :id2)';
    $res = $db->prepare($menu_query);
    $res->execute(array(':id' => $cat_main_id, ':id2' => $cat_add_id));
} else {
    die(header("Location: error.php"));
}
```